# Regexp problem in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a regexp problem in my htaccess.
I want to redirect all parameters in $_GET['params'] except css & js (these are folders) but the $_GET['params'] is empty :(

For example if i type : mydomain.com/its/an/example
Then $_GET['params'] = /its/an/example

But if i type : mydomain.com/js/its/an/example
It must be read like a folder.

So here is my code :

```
RewriteRule /!(css|js)(.*) /index.php?params=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Exclamation points in a regex don't negate. You're probably looking for something more like a negative lookahead (eg, `(?!css|js)`). But whether `mod_rewrite` supports that likely depends on server configuration and could cause server errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found...
No need to catch if it's a folder or not, i filter this with the native !-f and !-d :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?params=$1 [L]
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the `(.*)` part use $2

Or I suppose you could use `(?:css|js)` which would make it a passive group.

Comment: @Crazy are you trying to catch the .* part?